# Proving a matrix $A$ is of certain form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and $A=A^3$, prove that $A^2$ is of form $\begin{pmatrix}
I_r & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ where $1\leq r\leq n$.
It make sense. My initial thought was to say that $A(A-I)=0$ so $A=I$ or $A=0$. Which got me nowhere.
I thought about saying that $A^2$ is a projection, because $A^2=A^4$ and that pretty much ends it, from there its not hard to show what I need.
For some reason I want to see if there is a different way to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Your initial thought was false, first because the factorisation should be $A(A^2-I)=0$. Also, you forgot the ring of matrices has zero divisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ annihilates $A$ so it's diagonalizable. Hence there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that

$$A=P\operatorname{diag}(I_p,-I_q,0)P^{-1}$$
with $p+q=r$ so

$$A^2=P\operatorname{diag}(I_r,0)P^{-1}$$

Comment: So $A$ does not have to be of this form?

Comment: Could you give some details on why it is diaginalisable.

Comment: The mentioned polynomial has simple roots.@Bernard

Comment: I have made a mistake in the question!! please read again, it has been edited.

Comment: But if I found a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(A)=0$, does it mean it is the characheristic polynomial?

Comment: @YinonEliraz I edited my answer.

Comment: I didn't say that this polynomial is the characteristic polynomial but it's certainly a multiple of the minimal polynomial. Isn't it?@YinonEliraz

Comment: It is actually the minimal polynomial, isnt it? It annihilates $A$ and all it linear elements are of power $1$. But I didnt understand what does $diag(I_p,−I_q,0)$ means.

Comment: No we are not sure that it's the minimal polynomial since we are no sure that $0$ or $1$ or $-1$ are eigenvalue for $T$. $diag(I_p,-I_q,0)$ means a diagonal matrix with $p$ numbers $1$ and $q$ numbers $-1$ and the remain is $0$ on the diagonal.@YinonEliraz